# Sleep in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

greetings all
i want to make JQuery sleep/wait for a second between two functions

```
$('#div1').hide();
//sleep or wait or for a sec 
$("#div2").show();
```

how to do so ?

Comment: what about [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For your specific function [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) isn't queued, but there's an easy trick to make it queued so you can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), like this:

```
$('#div1').hide();
$("#div2").delay(1000).show(0);
```

By giving it a `0` duration argument, it's now an instant, but queued animation.  Underneath this uses [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), so it's basically the same behavior as:

```
$('#div1').hide();
setTimeout(function() { $("#div2").show(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: what about showing the div2 and wait for a second then show another div3 or do other JQuery code, is the behaviour differs in this case ?

Comment: @sword101 - It depends what you're after here, are you trying to do something generic, or loop through a set of elements?  If looping a simple `.each()` and taking the index and multiplying it by `1000` for a duration works well for example.

Comment: @sword101 - If it's generic you'll need to use an approach like above, setting timeouts or delays at needed...if it was something like a loop you could simplify it, but not in this case (unless your actions are on the same elements, in which case there's a queue per element that may help)...or a master queue on another element.

Answer (score 6):

Here ya go!

```
$('#div1').hide();
//sleep or wait or for a sec 
setTimeout('moomoo()', 1000);

function moomoo() {
  $("#div2").show();
}
```

Comment: your second `setTimeout` will not work. It needs a function reference so you need to skip the parenthesis after `moomoo`.

Comment: You can have anonymous function in there, will save the need in "proxy" function. :)

Comment: @Neurofluxation: I really would not recommend to someone to use `setTimeout` with a string argument. That will get evaluated by the Javascript engine, which is pretty slow. So it's best practice to pass a function reference to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Neurofluxation - on top of what @jAndy said, you're forcing `moomoo` to be a **global** function when calling it as a string, otherwise it won't work...also a negative.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do what you want:

```
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div2").delay(1000).show(0);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I forgot to add the duration. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

You can't just pause the execution of the code between the calls. That would mean that the browser would not display the change caused by the `hide` call, as no updates are done while the code is running. The code would just appear to do nothing.

Use the `setTimeout` method to schedule code to be executed at a later time:

```
$('#div1').hide();
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $("#div2").show();
}, 1000);
```

This will set the element as hidden and schedule the code to show it to start later. The code will continue after the `setTimeout` call so that the function can exit and the browser gets back the control so that it can actually hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

No real sleep, but this will achieve the same goal:

```
$('#div1').hide();
//sleep or wait or for a sec 
window.setTimeout(function() { $("#div2").show(); }, 1000);
```

Edit: well, I now stand corrected about "real" sleep, however using the setTimeout is still valid "pure JS" solution - your choice. :)