# Is there any Easier way to do setTimeout....?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, settimeout

I'm using following code to wait a java-script execution for 3 seconds.

```
var test = setTimeout(function(){
   alert("Test");
},3000);
```

My question is, If there is any easier way to do the same like following...
I have come across some blog which uses $.idle

```
$.idle(3000);
alert("Test");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sleep in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437600/sleep-in-jquery). You can't pause the thread in JavaScript, so the answer is pretty much "no".

Comment: Ok, I guess.. I should be using setTimeout only... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could remember the website where I pulled this so that I could give the author full credit, but what you may be looking for is a nice use of Deferreds in jQuery.

Here is a function that leverages Deferreds so that you have a clean, functional, calling mechanism very similar to what you showed ('cept that it doesn't block, as Andy E mentioned.)

```
$.wait = function(time) {
    return $.Deferred(function( dfd ) {
        // resolve() calls all of the registered
        // 'done' callbacks (registered using then())
        setTimeout(dfd.resolve, time);
    }).promise();
};
```

Now, thanks to the Deferreds, you can write timeouts in you app like this:

```
$.wait(5000).then(function() {
  alert("Hello from the future!");
});
```

Comment: Alright, I got it... This will only block any code inside .then function... This will work out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you after Delay?

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: `delay()` can't help here, because it's specifically for chaining jQuery animations.  You can't tack an `alert` onto `delay()` without making the whole thing more complicated than just using `setTimeout()`.  The docs you linked to even point out that *"[it] is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout"*.

Answer (score 1):

Call to setTimeout() is as fast as you can get, since this is native JS.