# Add delay in between two if conditions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to add a `wait()` or delay between two functions.

```
function(imageID)
    {
        //alert("i main slider called ");

        if(en==1)
        {
            var selected=$('#' + sel);
            $(selected).animate({"left": "+=30px","opacity": "0.99"},"slow");
            $(selected).animate({"height":"354px","width":"295px"},30);
            $(selected).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
            $(selected).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
            $(selected).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
            $(selected).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");
            $(selected).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(0deg)");
            $(selected).css("transform","rotateY(0deg)");
            en=0;
        }

        if(my.circular)
        {
            /* Trigger left jumppoint */
            if(imageID+1 === my.imageFocusMax)
            {
                /* Set jump target to the same cloned image on the right */
                clonedImageID = my.max - my.imageFocusMax;
                jumpTarget = -clonedImageID * my.xStep;

                /* Set the imageID to the last image */
                imageID = clonedImageID-1 ;
            }
```

In my function I want to add a delar after the if statement. How can I do that? I have tried adding `delay()` but it is not working.  What should I use?

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript

Comment: Here is the solution   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437600/sleep-in-jquery

Comment: First Why? Then how....

Comment: @Bondye first if condition is removing apllied css. and 2nd if is to slide image...   how to use setTimeout() in my case..

Comment: Why you don't use callback instead of delaying the application. You want to slide image when css is removed?

Comment: @Bondye first block is to remove css which is already applied , and yes then there is  series of if to slide image , Basically in my slider on selection of image  i have written code to bring image in Center, enlarge and rotate image .now when user will select any other Image then i have wriitten IF(see above) to remove all css then slide second image into center.

Comment: @simmisimmi: *"In my function I want to add a delar after the if statement."* You have more than one `if` statement in that code. Delay after which of them? Delaying which code? If you **show** us your `delay` attempt, we can probably help you. The reason you haven't gotten a useful answer is that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function. That way you can tell the browser to wait before doing something.